# How to throw object to the direction the player is facing?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to throw an object after it is being held. Here is how the pickup works:

```
 public void PickupObject()
        {

        physicsObject = lookObject.GetComponentInChildren<PhysicsObjects>();
        currentlyPickedUpObject = lookObject;
        pickupRB = currentlyPickedUpObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        priorConstraints = pickupRB.constraints;   
        pickupRB.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeAll;   
        pickupRB.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotation;
         physicsObject.playerInteractions = this;
        pickupRB.isKinematic = true;
        pickupRB.transform.parent = PickupParent.transform;
        //   pickupRB.isKinematic = true;
        StartCoroutine(physicsObject.PickUp()); 

    }
```

in the update():

```
 if (currentlyPickedUpObject != null)
        {
            currentDist = Vector3.Distance(PickupParent.position, pickupRB.position);
            currentSpeed = Mathf.SmoothStep(minSpeed, maxSpeed, currentDist / maxDistance);
            currentSpeed *= Time.fixedDeltaTime;
            pickupRB.transform.position = PickupParent.position;
            // pickupRB.transform.SetParent(PickupParent.transform);
            Vector3 direction = PickupParent.position - pickupRB.position;
            pickupRB.velocity = direction.normalized * currentSpeed;
            Vector3 camerDirection = mainCamera.transform.forward;
            // Throw object
            if (Throw)
            {
                pickupRB.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.None;
                pickupRB.isKinematic = false;
                Debug.Log("Object is being thrown"); 
                pickupRB.AddForce(camerDirection * 100);
            }
            Throw = false;
        }
```

as shown above I was trying to add force to the direction the player to be able to throw the item in that direction in this part:

```
Vector3 camerDirection = mainCamera.transform.forward;
if (Throw)
            {
            pickupRB.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.None;
            pickupRB.isKinematic = false;
                Debug.Log("Object is being thrown"); 
                pickupRB.AddForce(camerDirection * 100);
            }
            Throw = false;
```

The line is printed in the console when the throw button is pressed but nothing happens. How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're throwing the object but you're not releasing it, so on the next frame the `currentlyPickedUpObject` is not `null` so you go right back to moving it with the PickupParent again. Try setting it to null inside your `if (Throw)` statement so you don't keep moving it:

```
if (currentlyPickedUpObject != null)
    {
        currentDist = Vector3.Distance(PickupParent.position, pickupRB.position);
        currentSpeed = Mathf.SmoothStep(minSpeed, maxSpeed, currentDist / maxDistance);
        currentSpeed *= Time.fixedDeltaTime;
        pickupRB.transform.position = PickupParent.position;
        // pickupRB.transform.SetParent(PickupParent.transform);
        Vector3 direction = PickupParent.position - pickupRB.position;
        pickupRB.velocity = direction.normalized * currentSpeed;
        Vector3 camerDirection = mainCamera.transform.forward;
        // Throw object
        if (Throw)
        {
            pickupRB.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.None;
            pickupRB.isKinematic = false;
            Debug.Log("Object is being thrown"); 
            pickupRB.AddForce(camerDirection * 100);
            currentlyPickedUpObject = null; // <--- NEW
        }
        Throw = false;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, that's worked, but I had to add this line also: pickupRB.transform.parent = null; Thanks

Comment: @Okashi Glad you got it!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you pick the object up you are setting the pickupRB kinematic with line
`pickupRB.isKinematic = true`
So to fix this, you should add
`pickupRB.isKinematic = false`
before you add force to the rigidbody.

Comment: Yes I realized this might be the issue, so I added these two lines pickupRB.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.None;
                pickupRB.isKinematic = false; and still nothing happens.